# concat strings and insert as element to linked list java-collections

Tags: java, string, collections, foreach

INSonly(L) is the linked list, lets say the size is '5'
completelist(o) is the linked , lets say the size is '2'

if there is match in complete list like below:

```
"flagtrue"+ L +o

flagtrue01
flagtrue11
flagtrue21
flagtrue30
flagtrue40
```

I want to place all of the below strings as one string or element in linked list.

element1 ;should contain

```
flagtrue01
flagtrue11
flagtrue21
```

and

element2 : should contain

```
flagtrue30
flagtrue40
```

The values will be dynamic. please let me know if some one can help me on this.

```
for(int l=0;l<INSonly.size();l++ )
{
    memberid=INSonly.get(l); /*passed the element to string for each iteration*/
    for(int o=0;o<completelist.size();o++ ) /*complete list size '2'*/
    {
        if (memberid.contains(completelist.get(o))) /* if there is match */
        {
            System.out.println("flagtrue"+ l +o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what actually is your question?

Comment: want to place all of the below strings as one string or element in linked list. i mean to say what ever is matched with first element of complete list ,need to be concatenated and should be placed as element in new linked list

element1 ;should contain

flagtrue01
flagtrue11
flagtrue21
and

element2 : should contain

flagtrue30
flagtrue40

Answer (score 0):

what i have done is , used the same logic and i have created the collection frame work and place the matching values to respective directories and it is automatically matched. "if somebody having an issue like this in collection framework".

```
for(int l=0;l<INSonly.size();l++ )
{
    memberid=INSonly.get(l); /*passed the element to string for each iteration*/
    for(int o=0;o<completelist.size();o++ ) /*complete list size '2'*/
    {
        if (memberid.contains(completelist.get(o))) /* if there is match */
        {

String flag ="flag"+l +".txt";
String filedir =workdirectory + completelist.get(o) + "/";
File thedir =new File(filedir);
thedir.mkdir();
String filepath = filedir +flag;                
File file= new File(filepath);
if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
            }


    FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
   bw.write(memberid);
    bw.close();
```